# R: List files from directory with extension and name

Tags: r, substring

I am extracting some files from a directory as it follows and storing them in a data table:

```
FileList <- list.files(path = mydir, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE, all.files = TRUE )

FileList <- as.data.table(FileList)
```

A records in the obtained table looks like: dir/AA.csv
I would like to get two additional columns with the file name, e.g. xyz and the format, e.g. cvc, something like:

```
FileList[, Format : = "**help1**"] # in the example "csv"

FileList[, Name : = "**help2**"] # in the example "AA"
```

for the "help1": something to substring from the right till the first dot
for the "help2": something to substring from right till the first slash excluding the format at the end

Any elegant and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Fine for the extensions:   FileList <- FileList[, Extension := tstrsplit(FileList, "\\.")[[2]]]
  or FileList <- FileList[, Name := sub("^.+\\.", "", FileList)]. What about the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it in this way:

```
  FileList <- list.files(path = mydir, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE, all.files = TRUE )
  FileList <- as.data.table(FileList)
  FileList <- FileList[, Extension := tstrsplit(FileList, "\\.")[[2]]]
  FileList <- FileList[, Name := basename(FileList)]
  FileList <- FileList[, Name := gsub("\\..*","",Name)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with the tools package, which comes with R base. I load `dplyr` to use the pipe (`%>%`) and the `tibble()` function. From the `tools` package I use `file_ext()` and `file_path_sans_ext()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tools)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Considering I want to get the *.xlsx* files in the *data* directory

```r
mydir <- "data"
pattern <- "\\.xlsx"
FileList <- list.files(path = mydir, pattern = pattern, all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

my_data <- tibble(
    FileList = FileList,
    Format = file_ext(FileList),
    Name = list.files(path = mydir, pattern = pattern, all.files = TRUE) %>% file_path_sans_ext()
)

my_data

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# FileList                          Format Name                 
# <chr>                             <chr>  <chr>                
# 1 data/ali pei pat reference.xlsx xlsx   ali pei pat reference
# 2 data/ali pei pat.xlsx           xlsx   ali pei pat          
# 3 data/ali pei pci.xlsx           xlsx   ali pei pci          
# 4 data/ali pei pen.xlsx           xlsx   ali pei pen          
# 5 data/alineamiento pei pat.xlsx  xlsx   alineamiento pei pat 
# 6 data/alineamiento pei pci.xlsx  xlsx   alineamiento pei pci 
# 7 data/alineamiento pei pen.xlsx  xlsx   alineamiento pei pen 
# 8 data/lista de cotejo.xlsx       xlsx   lista de cotejo      
# 9 data/test.xlsx                  xlsx   test
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>